# Allow Group Creator/Owner Approve/Deny a user's request to join group

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I want to have the ability for `Users` to request to join a `Group` the person who created the group would be called `Owner` and any non-`Owner` would have to request to join `Owner`'s group. The `Owner` can approve or deny the request from the user. The `Owner` could also add users to their `Group` and the `User` could approve/deny the `Owner`'s request. Any suggestions on how to get started?

Answer (score 2):

I have a django app with identical requirements. Here's how I modeled it (of course there is no "right" way, it depends on your application's needs):

```
class User(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)   
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership', related_name='members', blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Membership(models.Model):
    # You can add other statuses depending on your application's needs
    STATUS_SUBSCRIBED = 0
    STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED = 1
    STATUS_REQUESTED = 2

    STATUS = (
    (STATUS_SUBSCRIBED, 'Joined'),
    (STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED, 'Unsubscribed'),
    (STATUS_REQUESTED, 'Requested'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS)

    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: So from a view, how would you allow the Group owner (`request.user`) to change the `members`s request status?